# When to add code to a users question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, suggested-edits

I've been trying to figure out what a user was asking as they were talking about a macro called 'Months' in their question, but hadn't shown any code.  The wording of the question made it possible that the user was talking about an Excel worksheet rather than any code.

The user uploaded the code in question to OneDrive and posted a portion of the code in the comments. I formatted the code and appended it to the bottom of the question so all could see it - and in my opinion it made the question easier to understand.

The edit was rejected though - 2 to 1 I think.
I'm just not sure why - 'This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.'
It wasn't an answer - it was the original code and the full code wouldn't fit as a comment.

When should we update questions with extra info provided by the original poster?

Comment: Well, your edit comment could have been clearer, for starters. For instance, _"Added code the OP posted in the comments to clarify the question."_ would have been clearer. Really, though, you should encourage the OP to edit their code in, and _then_ do so yourself if they don't/refuse to.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Kendra.  I'll know better next time. I was meaning to post the link - just forgot to at the last.

Comment: I've gone ahead and made the edit, based on the discussion here, and seeing the OP's OneDrive link. I'm open to criticism.

Comment: [Here's a link to the relevant review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10810314), it confirms the problem noted in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If that code was from the OP, then you did right.

However, you did not make it clear to the reviewers that the code came from the OP. They probably assumed that it was an attempt to answer the question.

Reviewers don't see the comments below a post, only the edit summary. So use the summary to say something like "Editing in code from comments and OneDrive link".